# "Bus error: 10" when running haxedoc

Tags: haxe

When running haxedoc, either from Haxe 2.08 or from Haxe 2.10, I get

```
$ haxe-2.10/haxedoc -h
Bus error: 10
```

Haxe 2.08 is the binary and my Haxe 2.10 was compiled with OCaml.
I suppose my Mac is using some incorrect library, causing the problem.

If I run `haxedoc` alone I get the same error. Finally if I run `sudo haxedoc -xml doc.xml build.hxml` to generate the xml file, I'm not getting any error, but the doc.xml file isn't generated.

Any idea what direction I can look towards?

Edit – Here is what the crash report file says:

```
Process:         haxedoc [4926]
Path:            /usr/lib/haxe-2.10/haxedoc
Identifier:      haxedoc
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [411]

Date/Time:       2014-08-10 09:40:42.986 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000

VM Regions Near 0:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /usr/lib/haxe-2.10/haxedoc
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000003000 [    8K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/haxe-2.10/haxedoc

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   haxedoc                             0x0000266c 0x1000 + 5740

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x0002f048  ebx: 0x0000255b  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0x002bae40  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0x002a9690  esp: 0xbffff920
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010246  eip: 0x0000266c   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x00000000
Logical CPU: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -     0x2ff6  haxedoc (??? - ???) <7F1DA0CB-B836-8F9E-7060-1E76C36AD6AD> /usr/bin/haxedoc
    0x6000 -    0x2eff3  libneko.dylib (??? - ???) <919F78D7-D3FE-8665-9FB9-8F435431BD8F> /usr/lib/libneko.dylib
   0xe7000 -    0xf7ff7  std.ndll (??? - ???) <2D9D0165-03D3-7F17-ECEB-F34780912F45> /usr/lib/neko/std.ndll
  0x266000 -   0x298fe7  regexp.ndll (??? - ???) <E320A465-95BD-0A2B-06D4-5483A4382904> /usr/lib/neko/regexp.ndll
0x8fe04000 - 0x8fe36aa7  dyld (195.6 - ???) <60FD3471-A1D7-342E-99A7-3EDECDAEC6EC> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90005000 - 0x90008ff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (6.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7F6C14CC-0169-3F1B-B89C-372F67F1F3B5> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x900a3000 - 0x900a3fff  libdnsinfo.dylib (395.11.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7EFAD88C-AFBC-3D48-BE14-60B8EACC68D7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x90fba000 - 0x90fbeff3  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <62EBADDA-FC72-3275-AAB3-5EDD949FEFAF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x91d14000 - 0x91d1cff3  liblaunch.dylib (392.39.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <9E6135FF-C2B1-3BC9-A160-B32D71BFA77C> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x92cb9000 - 0x92ce8ff7  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) <37640811-445B-3BB7-9934-A7C99848250D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x9309e000 - 0x9309fff4  libremovefile.dylib (21.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <6DE3FDC7-0BE0-3791-B6F5-C15422A8AFB8> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x94b9e000 - 0x94ba5ff9  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (??? - ???) <EBEAF723-84F8-3544-8FB2-31B7771B50D0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x95339000 - 0x95341ff5  libcopyfile.dylib (85.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <BB0C7B49-600F-3551-A460-B7E36CA4C4A4> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x95412000 - 0x954ddfff  libsystem_c.dylib (763.13.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <52421B00-79C8-3727-94DE-62F6820B9C31> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x95eac000 - 0x95ec2ffe  libxpc.dylib (77.19.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <0585AA94-F4FD-32C1-B586-22E7184B781A> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x9629d000 - 0x962a2ff7  libmacho.dylib (800.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <943213F3-CC9B-328E-8A6F-16D85C4274C7> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x968a7000 - 0x968afff3  libunwind.dylib (30.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <E8DA8CEC-12D6-3C8D-B2E2-5D567C8F3CB5> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x97066000 - 0x9706affa  libcache.dylib (47.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <56256537-6538-3522-BCB6-2C79DA6AC8CD> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x97740000 - 0x97741fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (53.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <B04592B1-0924-3422-82FF-976B339DF567> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x97871000 - 0x9789ffe7  libSystem.B.dylib (159.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <112D9C23-18FE-3995-A8DB-CDBE81CC7BAB> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x985f9000 - 0x985f9ffe  libkeymgr.dylib (23.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <7F0E8EE2-9E8F-366F-9988-E2F119DB9A82> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x996b7000 - 0x996b8ff0  libunc.dylib (24.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <2F4B35B2-706C-3383-AA86-DABA409FAE45> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
0x99a61000 - 0x99a62ff7  libquarantine.dylib (36.7.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <46980EC2-149D-3CF7-B29A-401FB89C275D> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
0x99b42000 - 0x99b49ff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (80.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <47DB9E1B-A7D1-3818-A747-382B2C5D9E1B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x9a0dc000 - 0x9a0faff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.32.7 - compatibility 1.0.0) <79179F83-457A-3539-A76B-E960D2108109> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x9aa00000 - 0x9aa0efff  libdispatch.dylib (187.10.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1B857064-288D-3919-B81A-38E9F4D19B54> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x9bea6000 - 0x9bea7ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <5CFCCFB7-CF29-3E04-801D-8532AE004768> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x9c284000 - 0x9c2c7ffd  libcommonCrypto.dylib (55010.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <6B35F203-5D72-335A-A4BC-CC89FEC0E14F> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x9c2c8000 - 0x9c2caff7  libdyld.dylib (195.6.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1F865C73-5803-3B08-988C-65B8D86CB7BE> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x9c2cb000 - 0x9c2ceff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <69357047-7BE0-3360-A36D-000F55E39336> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 1196
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=45.8M resident=10.4M(23%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=35.4M(77%)
Writable regions: Total=18.5M written=1156K(6%) resident=1224K(6%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=17.3M(94%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
MALLOC                             9316K
MALLOC guard page                    16K
Stack                              64.0M
VM_ALLOCATE                        1060K
__DATA                              484K
__IMPORT                             16K
__LINKEDIT                         43.1M
__PAGEZERO                            4K
__TEXT                             2720K
mapped file                       214.7M
shared memory                        12K
shared pmap                         9.9M
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             345.0M
```

Comment: This means its a fundamental problem with the software; not likely from you. If you check the logs `tail -f /var/log/system.log`, you'll likely see some `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or similar messages.

Comment: Rightly so! `Aug 10 09:40:44 ReportCrash[4928]: Saved crash report for haxedoc[4926] version ??? (???) to /Users/xxx/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/haxedoc_2014-08-10-094044_xxx.crash`  I'll cat the crash report into the original message. Thanks

Comment: It's probably a problem with a library reading xml, because running the unit test for haxe shows some tests fail with Xml.

Comment: Maybe post this one to the mailing list if you can't upgrade... it seems like a question for the compiler team. Though Haxe 2.10 isn't likely to get much in the way of community support ;)

Comment: Sure but I don't think it's a problem with haxedoc, as I said somewhere on this page, my neko unit test, right after compilation, are failing on the xml parsing tests. Since haxedoc seem to rely on xml parsing it's no wonder then it should fail. I'll inquiry and post more if I find where it comes from, but it's definitely related to my OSX system and one of its libs.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with your case:

1. You are running a *very old* version (2.10.0 was released July 2012). It is possible that the bug has been fixed in the latest build (3.1.3, released April 2014).
2. You are missing some libraries required for the product.

To solve both those problems, first delete the version you have installed now, then install the latest version using [`brew`](http://brew.sh/) with `brew install haxe`.